# Draggable items position mismatched

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

When dragging an element and dropping the droppable div.
This drag element is also cloned and resizable into droppable div.

But each element dragged into a droppable div position overlapping on the top of the box, not set a current position when the element clone and dragged to drop into the droppable div.

Is any way to solve the dragging item drop to a fixed position?

**HTML**

```
<div class="fields mb-md-1 pb-1" id="item1"> 
//drag item
  <div class="item-info"> 
    <input type="text" class="w-100 h-100 form-control" 
placeholder="Name"> 
  </div> 

  //droppable div
  <div class="file-viewer
position-relative" style="order: 2"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(".item-info").draggable({
     helper: 'clone',
     cursor: "move",
 });
 
 $(".file-viewer").droppable({
     accept: ".item-info",
     drop: function(e, ui) {
         $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
         $("#myList1 .item-info").addClass("new_item");
         $(".new_item").removeClass("ui-draggable item-info");
         $(".new_item").resizable({
             handles: "all",
             autoHide: true
         });
         $(".new_item").draggable({});
     }
 });
```

Comment: when the element is dropped inside another element, you just have a regular dom with a parent and children inside. Their position and everything else depends on classic styling. I made a simple demo with your code (if you included the html was much better) and I just have each box gets appended at the end of the parent next to the previous box. Did you expect it to keep the absolute position at the coordinates where you dropped it?

Comment: @DiegoDeVita well, I included the HTML, which element drag, and where element droppable, and also the clone item position: absolute, but didn't work perfectly yet.

Comment: for the sake of records I checked the jqueryui docs.. and its example works like you expected and it starts working like that when you invoke draggable() with no arguments. So there's something more to say there on draggable unless you want total control but I'm not aware of how unfortunately

Comment: Where is `#myList1` in your HTML? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example